# jQuery - Limit the number of video replays

Tags: jquery, html, video

I've got a working example of a control I need for a video (HTML5).  What I'm trying to figure out is how to make it replayable ONCE, and not more.  The code I have now brings back the replay button every time the video ends.  I'd like it to appear after the first play but not the second.  Thanks.

HTML:

```
<video id="erbVid" width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="Question_2_Video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#replayButton").hide();    
    $("video").bind("ended", function() {
        $("#replayButton").show();
    });
    $("#replayButton").click(function() {
        $("video")[0].play();
        $("#replayButton").hide();
    });    
});
```

Comment: seems like, if the user refreshes the page, then they will be able to watch the video again.  It would be easier to use a server side solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a varibale to check if the video has already been replayed and do something based on that variable eg.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create your boolean variable showing the video has not yet been replayed
    var replayed = false;

    $("#replayButton").hide();

    $("video").bind("ended", function() {
        // Check if the video has been replayed
        if(!replayed){
            // If not, do something and set replayed to true
            $("#replayButton").show();
            replayed = true;
        }
    });
    $("#replayButton").click(function() {
        $("video")[0].play();
        $("#replayButton").hide();
    });    
});
```

Once the video has been replayed the button to replay will no longer show. You could also do something like this to allow a number of replays:

```
var replayed = 0;
var replayed_max = 5;

$("video").bind("ended", function() {
    // Check if the video has been replayed the max number of times
    if(replayed < replayed_max){
        // If not, do something and add 1 to replayed
        $("#replayButton").show();
        replayed++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Worked perfectly, and helped my understanding of jQuery as well!

Comment: No probs, glad it helped :)